# Applescript - Write file in desktop

Tags: applescript

Im trying to write file in the desktop but it throws file not found error. I asked my code to create the file if no file but still show error. Below is my code.

```
tell application "Finder"

    try
        set myFile to ("TestReport.txt")
        set logpath to (((path to desktop from user domain) as string)) as alias
        set logfile to myFile
        tell application "Finder" to make new file at (logpath) with properties {name:myFile}
    on error --file exist yet, so create it
        set logfile to myFile as alias
        display alert logfile
    end try
    try
        tell application "Finder" to make new file at ((path to desktop from user domain) as string) with properties {name:"TestReport.txt"}
        set logmsg to "File Rename"
        --set logmsg to (numberoflines as string) & ") " & tab & mylogin & tab & curDate & tab & thecount & tab & "Ver.1" & return
        set the logdata to (open for access file (logfile as text) with write permission)
        write logmsg to the logdata starting at eof
        close access logdata
        return true
    end try
end tell
```

Please advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An "alias" file must exist. That's just how it works. Therefore if the path to your file doesn't exist, when you use "as alias", it will error. Another problem is the Finder will error when it tries to create the file if it already exists.

So you have two things that will make your code error. One when the file doesn't exist and the other when the file does exist. Pretty funny because your code will always error.

But it's a simple fix. You'll notice I keep all the paths as strings and when I want to use a path I put the word "file" or "folder" in front of it as appropriate. This converts the string path into a file specifier and allows it to be used. It also removes the need to use "as alias" and also allows me to add strings together to form the whole path. To fix the Finder problem we just check if the file exists before trying to create it. Try this...

```
set myFile to "TestReport.txt"
set logpath to (path to desktop from user domain) as string
set logfile to logpath & myFile
tell application "Finder"
    if not (exists file logfile) then
        make new file at folder logpath with properties {name:myFile}
    end if
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work even if `~/Desktop/file.txt` doesn't already exist:

```
set p to (system attribute "HOME") & "/Desktop/file.txt"
set fd to open for access p with write permission
write "text" & linefeed to fd as «class utf8» starting at eof
close access fd
```

Comment: This would append the text to an existing file, which was not clearly asked for (but implied from the details in the given example). To always overwrite an existing file, you'd add `set eof of the fd to 0` after the `open` line.